# prevent cutoff of imshow subplots of unequal dimension w/ sharex

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

I have several matrices I want to display with `imshow`, in subplots of the same figure.  They all have the same number of columns but varying number of rows.  I want to:

1. see all of each matrix when displayed with `imshow`
2. retain the `aspect=1` effect of `imshow`
3. use `sharex` in the figure

(which together imply that the heights of the subplots reflect the varying number of rows in the matrices).  I tried using `gridspec` (via the `gridspec_kw` argument of `plt.subplots`) but the combination of `sharex` and `aspect=1` leads to parts of the matrices getting cut off, unless I manually resize the window. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# fake data
foo = np.arange(5 * 7).reshape(5, 7)
bar = np.arange(11 * 7).reshape(11, 7)
baz = np.arange(3 * 7).reshape(3, 7)

data = [foo, bar, baz]
nrows = [x.shape[0] for x in data]
row_labels = np.array([x for x in 'abcdefghijk'])
col_labels = [x for x in 'ABCDEFG']

# initialize figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, squeeze=False, sharex=True,
                        gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=nrows))

for ix, d in enumerate(data):
    ax = axs[ix % axs.shape[0], ix // axs.shape[0]]
    _ = ax.imshow(d)
    _ = ax.yaxis.set_ticks(range(d.shape[0]))
    _ = ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(d.shape[1]))
    _ = ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_labels[np.arange(d.shape[0])])
    _ = ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(col_labels)
```

[image: resulting image with default figure dims]

Based on the number of rows in each matrix, I can guess at a ballpark figure dimension that *should* make them all visible, but it doesn't work:

```
figsize = (foo.shape[1], sum(nrows))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, squeeze=False, sharex=True,
                        gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=nrows),
                        figsize=figsize)

for ix, d in enumerate(data):
    ax = axs[ix % axs.shape[0], ix // axs.shape[0]]
    _ = ax.imshow(d)
    _ = ax.yaxis.set_ticks(range(d.shape[0]))
    _ = ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(d.shape[1]))
    _ = ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_labels[np.arange(d.shape[0])])
    _ = ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(col_labels)
```

notice how the top and bottom rows of all 3 subplots are partially cut off (it's easiest to see on the middle one) and yet there is a ton of excess whitespace at top and bottom figure margin:

[image: resulting image with custom figure dims]

Using `tight_layout` doesn't solve it either; it makes the subplots too big (note the gap at top/bottom of each subplot between axis spine and image):

[image: resulting image with custom dims and tight layout]

Is there any way to get `imshow` and `sharex` to work in harmony here?

Comment: (One of the big pains in mpl...)

Comment: Holy smokes is this a crazy issue!!!! I am no plotting guru... but damn was it hard to figure out that there is an issue between imshow in a subplot and sharing an axis!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered [`ImageGrid`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#imagegrid), which does the trick nicely. Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
foo = np.arange(5 * 7).reshape(5, 7)
bar = np.arange(11 * 7).reshape(11, 7)
baz = np.arange(3 * 7).reshape(3, 7)
data = [foo, bar, baz]
nrows = [x.shape[0] for x in data]
row_labels = np.array([x for x in 'abcdefghijk'])
col_labels = [x for x in 'ABCDEFG']
fig = plt.figure()
axs = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 1), axes_pad=0.1)
for ix, d in enumerate(data):
    ax = axs[ix]
    _ = ax.imshow(d)
    _ = ax.yaxis.set_ticks(range(d.shape[0]))
    _ = ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(d.shape[1]))
    _ = ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(row_labels[np.arange(d.shape[0])])
    _ = ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(col_labels)
```

[image: result using ImageGrid]